# Can you build an automatic carrot/potato/wheat farm INSIDE a village in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft Bedrock on Switch, and I want to build an automatic carrot and potato farm that uses villagers for harvesting.

I'm trying to plan out where I'll have a breeder and some other things. It'd be easier to place things if I could build the farm inside the village. Does this work?